# How can I add more than one database record to my HashMap?

Tags: java, sql, database, hashmap, jasper-reports

I have a HashMap that I am using to store information from my database. I have a Result Set that reads from each column of the database, and the Result Set is used to initialize a few string variables. These strings are then used in the HashMap. For example, one of my lines of code for my HashMap is `parameters.put("CertificateCode", CertificateCode);`. From what I'm beginning to understand, the first parameter of the HashMap allows the application to know WHERE to put the information, and the second parameter tells the HashMap WHAT information to put in.

Here is my problem... I noticed that if I try to run a loop through these lines of code, it will simply replace an existing value in the HashMap with the new one, thus only displaying the last record from my database.

How would I go about making the HashMap allow for the storage of multiple database records? I need this to work in a way that would still allow me to pass the parameters in to my Jasper Report. This method is `JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport()`, and it requires the parameters of `JasperReport`, `Map<String, Object>`, and a `Connection`.

I thought it might work if I added an array list to the HashMap. However, the "fillReport" method will not accept this as a proper parameter.

Any help would be much appreciated! I have been fighting with this reporting library for way too long now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap wont allow duplicate keys, when you try to insert value for a key which is already present inside the map then it will overwrite the key value with the new one.

If you want a map with duplicate keys then you have to go for  Guava's Multimap.